# Changing value of Block function from observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, blocks

I have an observer function on the event `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` that is pulling parameters out of the URL and modifying the cart based on the parameters.  This portion is all working fine.

However, there is a block injected by a 3rd party module that sets a value on radio buttons based on a function that evaluates settings in the Magento backend.  I would like to override the value returned by this function based on the results of my observer.

What would the best way to go about this be?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not the best way, but in your etc/modules/YOURMODULE.xml, you can add  something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YOUR_MODULE>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <3rdparty_Module/>
            </depends>
        </YOUR_MODULE>
    </modules>
</config>
```

This will allow your module be loaded after the 3rd party module, so it will override any similar functions.

Comment: Turned out to be a conditional error in the third party module and I had to edit that module itself which resolved the issue.